# Reading 32 ADC channels

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, stm32, multiplexer

I have been working on an application which must read

- 32 analog channels
- at least 200kS per second.
- 0 to +3.3V
- 12 bit resolution
- 1% accuracy

I've come up with 2 potential solutions:

- 32 ADC independent channels in STM32F303-familly MCU
- an analog multiplexer ADG732.

I'm aware that the implementation using a MCU would be way harder. What are potential problems in both methods.

Which solution looks better in your opinion?

Comment: Without knowing what your application and requirements (SNR, resolution, bandwidth, ect) this question is a matter of opinion and off topic as there is no definitive way to answer. They are both equally challenging and both require you to write software and create appropriate timing. With a mux you have to allow settling time before reading and you lose bandwidth from switching

Comment: What's wrong with 32 ADCs and an FPGA to control them - giving you synchronized readings? What accuracy are you requiring? What input voltage range do you hope to achieve? What errors are you able to tolerate? Plus the questions asked by laptop2d which isn't answered by saying 12-bit resolution is required.

Comment: Write specs for frame rate, resolution, Signal BW, Nyquist filter, error budget . e.g. frame rate x  32 channels x 12 bits = aggregate bit rate.    Define this, then decide on the implementation of serial, parallel,  DMA method, interleaved S&H, single/dual/quad mux etc. and kS "shud be" ks  . Maybe you have some slow channels that can be sub-channels.

Comment: "I'm aware that the implementation using a MCU would be way harder."  I can't see any other way to do it. Something has to control all the chip select lines, etc. and receive the data and something with it. Pass it along, write it to an SD card, etc.

Comment: 32 channels * 12 bits * 200 kHz = 76.8 Mbps. That's going to be a challenge for any microcontroller.

Comment: What does your system want to do with the samples? (store them; process them on the microcontroller; send them to a PC, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You need 6.4 Million samples per second. Various companies produce 12-bit ADCs to handle that rate.

I designed a 12-bit 4-channel system, for 24MegaSample/sec total, decades ago. We burned about 8 watts total. Gain per channel was 1/2/4/8. You want UNITY gain, so that saves power what with no gain being needed, and only one channel.

We used 8-layer PCB; the deterministic noise was below the 11-bit level. The random noise density was about 15 nanoVolts/rtHertz. In 4MHz bandwidth, that produces 30 microVolts rms, or about 185 microVolts PP (6.2 sigma, 6.2RMS).

You want 12 bits in 3.3v, or about 800 microVolts per Vquanta. But 1% accuracy: offset error, gain error, non-linearity. We used auto-zero of offset and of gain, about every 1 minute.

To handle 12 bits (9 nepers of settling) in 160 nanoseconds, you need precise timing of the ADC StartConvert event, so you can guarantee about 100 nanoseconds for settling. That means you need the MUX and the Buffer and the ADC input RC filter to produce 100nanosec / 9 nepers == 11 nanoseconds of ONE_POLE settling. 11*6.28 = 70, inverted to be 14 MHz F3dB for the entire signal Chain.

At high-frequencies, analog Muxes have LOTS OF CROSSTALK, and lots of charge injection from the on-silicon turn-those-MUX_FET-gates on/off very quickly.That means the 32 signal sources must be able to quickly recover from injected charge (remember that 11-nanosecond time constant, and 100nS settling time budget), or else you must **BUFFER** each of the 32 inputs with an OpAmp able to quickly settle.

Here is the idea

[image]

The stage#4, the RC LPF, is the **SLOWEST** stage by far, thus a clean settling channel-switching response can be expected, despite MUX charge injection; in the lower left corner, you'll see the far-out phase is 90 degrees, indicating a clean 1-pole rolloff. The opamps are MCP655, unity gain, with settling Taus of about 4 nanoseconds. The ADC has 500 ohms Rin and 5picoFarad Sample, thus 2.5 nanosecond sample-hold timeconstant; the ADC switch charge injection will vary depending on which ADC you pick. The combined RC LPF and its driving opamp must handle ADC charge injection.

Look at the topright numbers: the tool predicts 11.3 bits.

You have to handle offset and gain and non-linearity of the ADC and opamps.

======== now consider the interference from a nearby switching power supply ====

If you have such a supply 1cm away, switching 0.1 amp in 10 nanoseconds, the coupling being into a trace in the signal chain path, the tool predicts the ENOB will fall to 6.5 bits (7 milliVolts RMS induced error, using wire-to-loop coupling). This is **NOT** inductor-flux-leakage modeling.

That RC filter, at 14MHz, has little effect on SwitchReg frequencies. You need to **keep any Digital VDD traces at least an inch away from the Opamps and MUX and ADC input,** and keep that Digital VDD trace **OVER** a plane, so the net magnetic flux is greatly constricted to remain mostly very near and under the VDD trace

Answer (score 1):

Analog Devices makes an 8 & 16-channel simultaneusly sampled ADCs with 12 and more bits, but the results are still read out one channel at a time.
Use their filtering to pick one and use 2, 3, 4 of them.

https://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters/standard-adc/precision-adc-20msps/simultaneous-sampling-ad-converters.html

Comment: Still too expensive, but I keep that in mind.

Comment: If you have a cost limit, you need to add that to the question. But beware of turning this into a shopping question, which would be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> I've come up with 2 potential solutions

A ADG732 can only be part of the solution, because it's just a multiplexer ;-) There's no 12 bit ADC in it.

The STM32 has four independent ADCs and the datasheet specifies a min. total conversion time of 0.21µS - sounds great, but there are two issues:

- This MCU has a max. clock of 72MHz. I doubt that it's possible to process 9.6MB/s in time or transmit it safely to somewhere else.
- As the maximum total conversion time 8.52µs is specified, what would surely be a showstopper. The actual time is somewhere between min and max.

You will have to look for a different solution.

Comment: 72 MHz is fast enough to store or transfer 9.6MB/s. Total conversion time is programmable (sampling time is) and minimum is 0.194 μs (in fast mode). So neither of them are issue.

Comment: @Rokta I disagree, unless the ADC and data transmission are directly linked via DMA, assuming 1-clock instruction cycles, you have barely 8 instructions to read the data do any processing and put it in a communication channel. That leaves no margin for any type of processing or even communication handshaking.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, first you have 11 clock cycles between each conversion, and why wouldn't you use DMA? It is there for offloading CPU. For data output SPI is specified up to 18 Mbit/s, so plenty of reserve.

Comment: @Rokta 18Mbit/s is indeed quite fast for an SPI. But we need about 10 MB/s here ;-) And a DMA transfer may need more than 7 clock cycles - didn't check the datasheet (but I doubt it's specified at all)